# Error: No such file or directory passing env variable to working-directory in Github Workflow Actions

Tags: github, environment-variables, workflow, github-actions

I am setting up a workflow and I need to pass an `env` variable as the `working-directory`

Getting `Error: No such file or directory`

I've tried passing in the following env versions

`$base_directory`

`env."$base_directory"`

`"${base_directory}"`

The following works

```yaml
 - name: WORKING DIRECTORY
      run: |
        echo "HELLO"
      working-directory: ./base
```

I need this to work

```yaml
 - name: WORKING DIRECTORY
      env: 
        base_directory: ./base
      run: |
        echo "HELLO"
      working-directory: $base_directory
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked:

```
 - name: WORKING DIRECTORY
      env: 
        base_directory: ./base
      run: |
        echo "HELLO"
      working-directory: ${{ env.base_directory }}
```